# Is .htaccess directory restriction enough?

Tags: apache, drupal, e-commerce, security, ubercart

I'm building a Mp3 store with Drupal and Ubercart. I would like to implement the best security measures to proctect the content from hackers etc. I have a file directory with .htaccess file

Contents of the .htaccess file

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Deny from all
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Is this enough or should the mp3 files be stored outside of the webroot?

Does VPS Hosting provide better security than shared hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have set file system to Private and files will be transferred via Drupal.
From my experience, it works and it's almost secure, unless:

1. A third party can access your server via FTP or a higher protocol.
2. A user can gain access to execute PHP.
3. Make sure that, if you have IMCE or other file browser module enabled, these secured folders are not allowed to access.
4. Whatever plan you have, hosting company  has access to your files. But usually, a **correctly configured** can be more secure than a shared host because you can use private temporary folders, and you can have more control over who can access your server and banning bad guys.

Comment: How possible is it that a 3rd party gains FTP access to my server? without obtaining my FTP login details?

Comment: They can brute-force, that means guessing a number of possible passwords. It's similar to gaining access to your other online accounts while FTP can do a more damage to your business. Consider using public/private keys to authenticate yourself over FTPS connections.

Comment: Ok thanx Ayesh. I'm familiar with brute-force :)